# Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection.getEncoding()Lorg/postgresql/core/Encoding;

Tags: postgresql, maven, ibatis

I'm with a problem, my project uses **postgreslq-jdbc** jar and **postgis-jdbc** jar. I put it on my maven pom, and now I can't connect to database. I updated the postgreslq-jdbc.jar version to 9.4 the same as my Postgre.

Any suggestion?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection.getEncoding()Lorg/postgresql/core/Encoding;
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getInt(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2009)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getInt(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2366)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.type.IntegerTypeHandler.getResult(IntegerTypeHandler.java:35)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.ResultMap.getPrimitiveResultMappingValue(ResultMap.java:626)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.result.ResultMap.getResults(ResultMap.java:345)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.handleResults(SqlExecutor.java:384)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.handleMultipleResults(SqlExecutor.java:300)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.executeQuery(SqlExecutor.java:189)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.sqlExecuteQuery(MappedStatement.java:221)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(MappedStatement.java:189)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForList(MappedStatement.java:139)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:567)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:541)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:118)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:122)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryForList(SqlMapClientImpl.java:98)
at com.ibatis.dao.client.template.SqlMapDaoTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapDaoTemplate.java:300)
```

Comment: Can you please post the error that you get and maybe your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I've found the solution, I changed the project dependencies and removed the jars ambiguities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you use the wrong version of class

```
org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection
```

Also you could use the wrong version of code that calls this class.